# Is this phrase uttered by Roland Blum a reference to Braindead?

Tags: reference, the-good-fight, braindead

During the first few episodes of the TV series *The Good Fight's* third season, viewers are introduced to a scrupulous diabolical character named Roland Blum (Micheal Sheen) and whose entry point in the story relates to having to work alongside Maia Rindell (Rose Leslie) in court, as their clients are adjoined together in a case.

[image: The Good Fight 3.02)]

Maia comes off as being a very green and *follow-the-rules* kind lawyer, due to a non-aggressive or non-assertive personality, which has been contested lightly over the course of the series thus far, but Roland Blum seems to believe she's an "assassin" underneath of what he sees as a false facade. Although he may just be trying to corrupt her.

However, as means to antagonize her, he begins to refer to her as a **"Mary Elizabeth".**

On the surface that comment seems to be a one off referring to Maia as a [Mary Sue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Sue), playing into *The Good Fight's* more surreal themes of the nonsensical, because he calls her something similar, but yet other and of course Elizabeth is not her name, nor is Maia a perfect *goody-two-shoes* either...

But the executive producers, creators, writers of this series, Michelle and Robert King also worked on a series between *The Good Wife* & *The Good Fight* titled *Braindead*.

*Braindead* was a science-fiction political satire about ant-like parasites from outer space coming to Washington D.C. and eating half the people's brains and using their bodies as hosts! The human hosts then would only listen to *The Cars*, "You Might Think", were disgusted by human sexual intercourse, and no longer ate "junk food", but rather vegetables and "green" veggie-shakes. This was a creative way to explain the political climate and polarization away.

*The Good Fight* seems like it has made ongoing references and/or allusions to *Braindead* from time to time and it so happens that *Braindead's* lead actress was played by non-other than **Mary Elizabeth** Winsted!

[image: Braindead]

In addition, Aaron Tveit, who was playing opposite Mary Elizabeth Winstead on *Braindead*, now reoccurs on *The Good Fight* and is now apart of this Maia and Roland Blum storyline by playing an AUSA opposite them in court. Roland Blum is also seen in one scene drinking something out of a "green" Gatorade-like bottle, commenting how gross he thinks it is (because it's not drugs or alcohol, which he prefers).

### So anyways, I was wondering if this "Mary Elizabeth" comment was an intentional reference back to Mary Elizabeth Winstead's character, Laurel Healy, on *Braindead* or is there some additional reference I'm missing?